# How to check for parameter type?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made my own Ajax "generic" (cant remember how you call this principle in C#) like this (only relevant functions):

```
public class Ajax<T> 
{
    public delegate void CallbackAjaxFinished(T j);
    public void Get(string Url, CallbackAjaxFinished cbAjaxFinished)
    {
        /* blablah launch the Ajax call which calls back GetFinished() below */
    }
    private void GetFinished(HTTPRequest request, HTTPResponse response)
    {
        ConvertThenCallback(response, true);
    }
    private void ConvertThenCallback(HTTPResponse response, bool isGet)
    {
        try {
            /* make conversion, T could be for example class JsonData */
            j = (T)JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(response.DataAsText);
        } catch (ArgumentException) { /* Conversion problem */
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

That was working well, like this:

```
Ajax<JsonState> a = new Ajax<JsonState>();
a.Get(
    baseURL + _urlGetState, /* get Url */
    /* callback Ajax finished: */
    (JsonState j) => { /* do stuff in the callback */ }
);
```

The problem is that Unity's `JsonUtility` doesnt handle nested arrays (...).

To make a long story short, I'd like in my "generic" stuff, to pass a custom "json decode" function callback, default=`null`, and in the `ConvertThenCallback()` function, do this:

- if there's no custom function, call `j = (T)JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(response.DataAsText);` (like it already is now)
- if there's a custom function, call something like `j = (T)callback(response.DataAsText);`

How would you do that in `C#`?

---

Update

Here's my `JsonState` + dependencies declaration:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class JsonGameDataCell
{
    public JsonGameDataBoatCurrentPlayerShot[] c;
    public JsonGameDataBoatOpponentShot[] o;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class JsonGameData
{
    public JsonGameDataStart start;
    public JsonGameDataCell[][] board;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class JsonData
{
    public string player;
    public JsonGameData game;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class JsonState
{
    public int state;
    public int state_sub;
    public string message;
    public JsonData data;
}
```

And my actual problem is that Unity `Json` utility can't decode nested arrays, so the property `JsonGameDataCell[][] board` is always set to `null` when I call `JsonUtility.FromJson()`. So I have to implement my own Json decoder. I'll use `SimpleJSON` which works very well, but I just want to use thise decoder *only in that specific case*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you're seeking something called an `interface`. You can use them to mark some objects so that the application "knows" how to treat them.

You can create such `interface` as such :

```
public interface ICustomJson
{
    void FromJson(string jsonString);
}
```

Now in your `ConvertAndCallback`you can just check `if(typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(ICustomJson)))`

If it does you can just create an instance of that class casted to `ICustomJson` and call `FromJson(string)` method.

Remember that your object can have no default ( parameterless ) constructor so you can create an uninitialized version of that class.

---

*example `ConvertAndCallback`:*

```
T result = null;
if(typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Any(i => i == typeof(ICustomJson)))
{
    result = (T)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T));
    ((ICustomJson)result).FromJson(string);
}
else
{
    result = (T)JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(response.DataAsText);
}
```

---

Another solution would be ( again ) to use an `interface` but only for deserializer part. This will involve another class ( or a factory ) to produce a deserializer for the specified type.

You can create an interface called `IJsonSerializer` with two methods inside `T Deserialize(string)` and `string Serialize(T)`:

```
public interface IJsonSerializer<T>
{
    T Deserialize(string jsonString);
    string Serialize(T jsonObject);
}
```

Now having this interface, create a class which will implement this

```
public class JsonStateSerializer : IJsonSerializer<JsonState>
{
    public JsonState Deserialize(string jsonString)
    {
        // put your deserialization code up in here
    }

    public string Serialize(JsonState jsonObject)
    {
        // put your serialization code up in here
    }
}
```

Now create the default one:

```
public class DefaultJsonSerializer<T> : IJsonSerializer<T>
{
    public T Deserialize(string jsonString)
    {
        return (T)JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(jsonString);
    }

    public string Serialize(T jsonObject)
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

Having these two would be easier to distinguish which one to use later in your `ConvertAndCallback` method.

Now if you want you can create some `Attribute`s to mark which serializer will be applied to which object or use some factory for that.

I will go with the easiest method and just modify `ConvertAndCallback` method so that it will have another ( optional ) parameter.

```
void ConvertThenCallback(HTTPResponse response, bool isGet, IJsonSerializer<T> serializer = null)
{
    try 
    {
        if(serializer == null)
        {
            serializer = new DefaultJsonSerializer<T>();
        }
        j = serializer.Deserialize(response.DataAsText);
    } 
    catch (ArgumentException) 
    {
        /* Conversion problem */
        return;
    }
}
```

And apply this to your `Get` method too ( so that the serializer would be passed from public to private methods ):

```
public void Get(string Url, CallbackAjaxFinished cbAjaxFinished, IJsonSerializer<T> serializer = null)
{
    // whenever you call ConvertAndCallback
    ConvertAndCallback(param1, param2, serializer); // just pass the same serializer here
}
```

You can now use it with any kind of serializer that implements `IJsonSerializer<T>` interface or with the default one if none specified.

*example usage:*

```
Ajax<JsonState> a = new Ajax<JsonState>();
a.Get(
    baseURL + _urlGetState, /* get Url */
    /* callback Ajax finished: */
    (JsonState j) => { /* do stuff in the callback */ },
    new JsonStateSerializer()
);
// or if you want to use default one
Ajax<JsonState> a = new Ajax<JsonState>();
a.Get(
    baseURL + _urlGetState, /* get Url */
    /* callback Ajax finished: */
    (JsonState j) => { /* do stuff in the callback */ }
);
```

---

I don't quite understand what you meant but will answer the part I do. Please clarify in the comment if that's what you wanted or if there's something unclear in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll try to clarify: I want a generic `Ajax<T>` where in the `ConvertAndCallback()` method I either use a custom "decoder" of my own, or, if there's no custom "decoder" the default standard decoder (`JsonUtility.FromJson`) and I dont know how to makes things the `C#` way (= good job, not disgusting job).

Comment: I've updated my question with my JsonState + dependencies declaration (especially a more precise explanation at the end)

Comment: @OlivierPons While the method above could actually work with your case I'll add another solution which ( IMHO ) would be a better fit in your case.

Comment: Wow what a great answer, thank you very much, I was very close to your solution #2 but I'm lacking knowledge in `C#`, I'll use your solution, thank you very much! Now I'll have to explode my code into multiple files, but that's another `C#` story!

Comment: @OlivierPons Thank you for the feedback and I hope that it will help you :)