# Parse JSON response with different content

Tags: c#, rest, api, json.net

On request `A` I am getting response:

```
{  
   "session":{  
      "lifetime":"600",
      "sid":"qweasdzxc:"
   },
   "httpStatus":200,
   "response":{  
      "state":"password",
      "token":"foobar123",
      "next_state":"dispatch"
   }
}
```

and on request `B` I am getting another response:

```
{  
   "session":{  
      "lifetime":"600",
      "sid":"qweasdzxc:"
   },
   "httpStatus":200,
   "response":{  
      "origin":"NORMAL",
      "activate_bpa":false,
      "state":"dispatch",
      "next_state":"STOP"
      "is_nordea":false,
      "login_type":"NORMAL"
   },
   "data":{
      "img_src":"example.com"
   }
}
```

There are few differences between responses. How should I handle it?

My first idea was to create classes which will hold all possible data:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public Session session { get; set; }
    public int httpStatus { get; set; }
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}

public class Session
{
    public string lifetime { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string next_state { get; set; }
    public bool activate_bpa {get; set;}
    public string origin {get; set;}
    public bool is_nordea { get; set;}
    public string login_type {get; set;}

    public Data Data {get; set;}
}

public class Data
{
    public string img_stc {get; set;}
}
```

Now, I can get data from request `A` and `B` and parse two of them to `BaseResponse` like this:

```
var aParsed = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<BaseResponse>(aContent);
var bParsed = JsonConverter.DeserializeObject<BaseResponse>(bContent);
```

The problem is, that `aParsed` will contains `origin`, `activate_bpa` (and more) properties, which will never be set. I would like to have object with properties which are in response.

I can't really create two different `Response` classes in same namespace. What should I do then?

Comment: Even though it was a different question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937026/how-to-check-for-parameter-type/47937392#47937392) might really help you out with your problem.

Comment: Actually, given that sample json, shouldn't `Data` belong to `BaseResponse` instead of `Response`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use some automatic deserialization mechanism use generics.

```
public class BaseResponse<T>
{
    public Session session { get; set; }
    public int httpStatus { get; set; }
    public Response Response { get; set; }

    public T Data {get; set;}
}

...

public class Data
{
    public string img_stc {get; set;}
}
```

Then deserialize using specifing *data* class

```
var response = JsonConverter.Deserialize<BaseResponse<Data>>(json);
```

You could do the same with *Response* class

```
public class BaseResponse<TD, TR>
{
    public Session session { get; set; }
    public int httpStatus { get; set; }
    public TR Response { get; set; }

    public TD Data {get; set;}
}

var response = JsonConverter.Deserialize<BaseResponse<Data, ResponseA>>(json);
```

Comment: But what about `Response`? There are two different responses I can get.

Comment: Make _Response_ property in _BaseResponse_ class generic.

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialize them into dynamic objects via,

JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm

Then you could refer the properties in the obejct via dot(.) notation like,
obj.origin, obj.state ...ect.

But you will lose the compile time type checking here and there is no base data structure/s for responses.

Answer (score 0):

Use  dynamic as datatype for your response

```
public class BaseResponse
{

    public Session session { get; set; }
            public int httpStatus { get; set; }
            public dynamic Response { get; set; }
}
```